# How to use Lucene.Net Highlight feature to implement this?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I use Lucene.Net 2.9.2. I want to use the *highlight* feature to implement this function:

```
highlighter.Keyword = "wiping citroen berlingo";
highlighter.StartTag = "<span>";
highlighter.EndTag = "</span>";

var text = "The Citroen Berlingo has two windscreen wipers at the front and one wiper at the back.  They're great for wiping stuff away.";
```

I wanted this result:

```
"The <span>Citroen</span> <span>Berlingo</span> has two windscreen <span>wipers</span> at the front and one <span>wiper</span> at the back.  They're great for <span>wiping</span> stuff away."
```

But I got this:

```
"The <span>Citroen</span> <span>Berlingo</span> has two windscreen wipers at the front and one wiper at the back.  They're great for **<span>wiping</span>** stuff away."
```

What might be causing this difference?

Comment: show us some code so we can figure out where these asterisks in the output come from

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not stemming your input. Try using the Porter stemmer, for example.